# what is the difference between .got.plt and .plt.got section?

Tags: c++, c, security, compiler-construction, elf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, int *argv[])
{

  size_t *p = (size_t *) strtol(argv[1], NULL, 16);

  p[0] = 0xAAAAAAAA;

  printf("RELRO: %p\n", p);

  return 0;
}
```

After compiling the above code with with parameters `gcc -g -Wl,-z,relro -o test test.c`
and listing all the sections using `readelf` it shows following sections

```
Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Address          Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
                                ..........
  [23] .got              PROGBITS        0000000000403ff0 002ff0 000010 08  WA  0   0  8
       +---------+
  [24] |.got.plt |       PROGBITS        0000000000404000 003000 000028 08  WA  0   0  8
       +---------+
                                ..........
```

and compiling the same binary with parameter(without relro) `gcc -Wl,-z,norelro  -o test test.c` and listing all the sections using `readelf` it shows following sections

```
Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Address          Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
                               ..........
  [13] .plt              PROGBITS        0000000000001020 001020 000030 10  AX  0   0 16
       +---------+
  [14] |.plt.got |       PROGBITS        0000000000001050 001050 000010 10  AX  0   0 16
       +---------+
                               ..........
```

**My doubt is what is the difference between these two sections .got.plt and .plt.got ?**

Comment: check loinker script

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58076539/plt-plt-got-what-is-different